# How can I access a property of a step component from the parent page of a Vue stepper?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-stepper

Not very experienced with Vue, and am struggling to fix an issue with an existing component made by a previous developer.

On the parent page, the `stepper` component is declared like this, with these as the names of the sub-components that make up the individual steps:

```
@Component({
    name: 'switch-stepper',
    components: {
        Stepper,
        StepIndicator,
        FirstStep,
        SecondStep,
        ThirdStep
    }
})
```

There's a property in `ThirdStep` that needs to be changed, either in the parent page or in `FirstStep`. The property in question is public, and declared like this:

```
@Prop({ default: true })
public myBooleanProperty: boolean;
```

However, inside the parent page, if I try this:

```
ThirdStep.myBooleanProperty
```

It is not recognised by the intellisense and is undefined. I've tried also creating a public method on `ThirdStep` that I can call to use `ForceUpdate` but public methods likewise seem to be inaccessible.

I've also tried setting the public property via a function in the parent page when the step is created:

```
<third-step :page="page"
            :step="steps[4]"
            :myBooleanProperty="setMyBooleanProperty()"
            v-show="currentStep === steps[4]">
</third-step>
```

But as far as I can tell this is only called once when the step is created and never accessed again.

What can I do to set the property of this child step via other components in the stepper?

Answer (score 1):

> *There's a property in ThirdStep that needs to be changed, either in the parent page or in FirstStep. The property in question is public,
> and declared like this:*

If a property needs to be changed, it should be changed in the component which returns the property in the data property. By this, I mean, the component that has

```js
data() {
  return {
    myBooleanProperty: false // or true. This is the local data that will be initialised and passed as props to the ThirdStep component
  }
}
```

If this is in the parent page, change `ThirdStep.myBooleanProperty` to `this.myBooleanProperty = *enter value*`. The change of the value of `myBooleanProperty` can be done in a method, watcher, computed property etc. The reason `ThirdStep.myBooleanProperty` is not working in the parent component, is that each vue component is a Vue instance and `ThirdStep` cannot have access to an instance property in the parent component.

#### ParentComponent.vue

```js
@Component({
    name: 'switch-stepper',
    components: {
        Stepper,
        StepIndicator,
        FirstStep,
        SecondStep,
        ThirdStep
    }
})
```

```html
<third-step>
  ...
  :myBooleanProperty="myBooleanProperty" // my boolean property is passed as props from the parent component, I assume
  ....>
</third-step>
```

When `myBooleanProperty` is changed where it is initialised (parent component, I assume), this will cause the value of the `myBooleanProperty` props, passed into the `ThirdStep` component, to change and there will be a re-render of the parts of the `ThirdStep` component that use `myBooleanProperty` props.

Comment: Thanks: this is similar to what I've already tried. Just attempted to reconstruct it and the property does not appear to be reset in the child when it's changed in the parent.

Comment: For you to receive help, you would need to post more code. Can you edit the post, please?